# Open modal dialogue in catch block

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, modal-dialog

I have this code in my action

```
var singedUser = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

        try
        {
            _purchaseService.PurchaseCard(singedUser, cardName);
        }
        catch
        {

        }
```

And I want this to open ONLY if the code enters the catch block

```
<div id="Modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Purchasing Card</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>You have unsufficient funds!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my button

```
<a class="button btn btn-success" 
    asp-controller="Store" asp-action="Buy" 
    asp-route-data ="@card.Name">Buy (@card.Price coins)</a>
```

I would appreciate if someone would tell me how I can open this dialogue box in the same page only if the code enters the catch block

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an ajax call to return the partial view and add it to the DOM. Setting up a modal to load a partial view is actually pretty straight forward :

1. Create partial view : _ModalContent.cshtml

   ```
   <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
           <h4 class="modal-title">Purchasing Card</h4>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
           <p>You have unsufficient funds!</p>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```
2. Modify your Index page :

   ```
   <a id="button1" class="button btn btn-success" 
   asp-controller="Store" asp-action="Buy" 
   asp-route-data ="@card.Name">Buy (@card.Price coins)</a>

   <div id="myModal"></div>

   @section Scripts{

   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
       $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
       $("#button1").on("click", function (e) {
           $('#myModal').load(this.href, function () {
               $('#Modal').modal({
                   keyboard: true
               }, 'show');
           });
           return false;
       });
   });
   </script>
   }
   ```
3. Controller function :

   ```
   public IActionResult buy(string data)
   {
       .....
       {

           return PartialView("_ModalContent");
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks! I will look up that one, because I couldn't get a hold of the Viewbag one :)

Comment: @Edwardcho , if the reply helps , you can mark that as answer .

Comment: I am sorry, but I think I need a few adjustments to do here and there, since it opens a blank new page with the modal content :/ and I want the modal to display itself in the same page if the purchase is declined

Comment: @Edwardcho , No ,it wouldn't open a new page . Try the codes in a new page ,

Answer (score 0):

I would pass a variable through the ViewBag on the controller/action.  Something like this in the controller:

```
            var singedUser = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

        try
        {
            _purchaseService.PurchaseCard(singedUser, cardName);
        }
        catch
        {
            ViewBag.ShowModal = false;
        }
```

Then toggle whether or not to trigger JQuery to show the Modal in the scripts section of the view:

```
@section Scripts{
<script>
    @if(ViewBag.ShowModal == true){
        @Html.Raw("$('#Modal').modal('show');");
    }
</script>
}
```